# Count of participants(by defination)

Tags: skype, counting, group-policy

I want to know how we should count the number of participants in a group? For example I creat a group and add two of my friends.

Now how many participants should be there (2 or 3)?
Should it include myself as well?

Because skype does not include yourself in participant count.

Comment: The context of this question is quite unclear, I think. What language are you using on what system? What API call are you using to query Skype? What function? Please provide much more context and detail. In the current phrasing, it is unclear if this is a programming question or a Skype usage question.

Comment: As far as I understand question it is about how to count users for licensing purposes. Am I right?

Comment: sorry but this is a general question about skype usage. because when we look at no. of participant in a group on skype it doesn't count yourself.